# Designing a DB backed application in a functional style

Tags: functional-programming

When designing a program in a functional style, I think about designing a base layer of functions that operate on a single object. Then, if I need to operate on a collection of those objects I start building on top of that base layer using traditional functional glue like mapping, filtering, reducing, etc.

For example, lets say I have a DB backed application that has Users and Tasks, where Users are assigned Tasks.

I may have a function defined like

```
def doesUserPerformTask?(taskId, userId)
  // Go to DB to see if this userId does this taskId
  // return userid if success or else nil
end
```

Later down the road, I am given a list of user id's and want to know which of them perform task X. Perfect, I already have the function `doesUserPerformTask?` and it has been battle tested all over other places in the code, so I can just map over the user id list and call that function for each of them and then filter the results.

While this is a great benefit of functional design, I have an efficiency problem that each element (i.e. user id) passed to map requires a DB hit. I now need to create an entirely new function that operates on a list of userId's.

I keep running into this problem when designing DB backed programs in a functional style, where I keep having to write new functions that don't build off the base layer of functions and ending up with lots of functions written specifically for both operating on single items and collections of items.

Is there a better way to organize DB backed programs written in a functional style?

Comment: Besides *not doing it*?  Some things just aren't FP's strong suit.  Zealotry notwithstanding.

Comment: Who knows, maybe when solid-state drives become cheaper/faster/larger, the border between RAM / disk will become more blurred, the performance penalties will disappear, and the style of programming you propose will make sense. In the meantime, how about a cache?

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the actual object into the function?

```
def doesUserPerformTask?(task, user)
  // Check the user object directly
  // return true or (false|nil)
end
```

Then write a wrapper that will fetch the user and task from the DB

```
def doesUserPerformTaskFromDB?(taksId, userId)
  // DB calls here
  if doesUserPerformTask?(task, user) ? user.id : nil
end
```

Then write a wrapper for collections

```
def whichUsersPerformTask?(task)
  // fetch users from DB
  // map non-db function over collection
end
```

Then again, unless you're going to use that user collection for something else wouldn't it be better to depend upon the DB query to get the users you need (via whichever query language)? Seems like there are a few options that make this both efficient and DRY.